# Is it Possible generate flash light according to binary code at smartphone?

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I would like to get some feedback or advise from you all which are much expert then me.
I have done this project before and find out some issue, I try my best to solve still cant work :(

In short, I use android studio to generate a random() code and convert to binary, let said "0101101101011011" and I want phone to flash according to the Binary code. 0= Off flash 1=On flash. I realize that some phone can work some phone cannot work, and the android version I compile is 4.0.3 . I install that apps at above 4.0.3 version phone.

Is it hardware limitation? Or any suggestion to do that ? Thanks for advise and suggestion ~

Comment: android flashLight blinks on binary code only. if your flashlight is not working than you can use the base code to switch ON/OFF flash.

Comment: At Phone1 : flash 01011010 at 5second with correct pulse period that I measure using oscilloscope
At Phone2 : flash 01011010 at 1 seconds with incorrect pulse period that I  measure using oscilloscope. 
How to do standardization on all android phone flash light ?

Comment: update your code here than only somebody will gonna help you on this.